# Experimenting with l3box and l3skip's dim variables

Tags: latex3, xparse

Note: The following MWE has no significance in use or further application of any kind rather than just for experimenting with the packages explicitly written on the question title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_shcstyle_instruction_length
\dim_set:Nn \l_shcstyle_instruction_length { 8em }

\box_new:N \l_shcstyle_bullet_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_shcstyle_bullet_box { \textbullet\  } 

\NewDocumentCommand{\mybulletpar}{ m }
 {
    \parbox{\dim_use:N \l_shcstyle_instruction_length}
     {
      \hbox_overlap_left:n 
       { 
        %\box_move_up:nn { 0ex }
         %{
          \box_use:N \l_shcstyle_bullet_box 
         %}
       } 
      #1
     }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
This is a \mybulletpar{some random text used to test newcommand}

\end{document}
```

So I have been toying around with some of the LaTeX 3 packages, especially `l3box` and `l3skip` since they seemed easy to understand, but what am not sure is of their proper usage and implementation in commands. For example, the MWE above I created a new dimension; I suppose I named it correctly by putting it local. After which, I set its size to `8em`. Then I created a box and used it to set the contents of an `hbox`. Nothing hard so far. I then tried to use the `\hbox_overlap_left:n { box }` command to somewhat act like an `\llap{<content>}`. (Am not really sure if it is its proper use.) But note that when I use the box I created `\box_use:N \l_shcstyle_bullet_box`, it creates an empty line. Weird? I honestly am just experimenting on this.

Any insights and corrections of naming, usage or other sample implementations of the commands would help me better understand LaTeX 3. Note that `interface3` only provides some descriptions of the commands.

I am also interested in seeing how to use the following commands:

- `\box_move_right:nn {<dimexpr>} {<box function>}`
- `\box_move_left:nn {<dimexpr>} {<box function>}`

and those commands involving 
 - `\vbox:n {<contents>}`

Comment: At the start of the parbox, TeX is in vertical mode.  In this mode, it will stack boxes vertically, and in particular the (horizontal) box created by `\hbox_overlap_left:n` is placed entirely above the paragraph of text which follows.  Add `\leavevmode` before `\hbox_overlap_left:n` to go to horizontal mode: then the bullet and the following text will be considered as a single paragraph.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Is there a LaTeX 3 equivalent to `\leavevmode`? Thanks by the way. The implementation of `\leavevmode` was my last resort. :-) Also how can you tell when it is in vertical mode?

Comment: @azetina AFAIK there isn't. Something like `\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_leave_vmode: { \hbox_unpack:N \c_empty_box }` would work but why not simply use `\leavevmode`?

Comment: @cgnieder I have nothing against `\leavevmode`. It's just that am trying to gain as much as I can from learning LaTeX 3. At the moment no one has made any suggestions as to how I defined my commands and if am using the syntax correctly. Thanks for the input on `\my_leave_vmode`.